# expand TreeView (parent)nodes which contains selected item

Tags: recursion, treeview, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a TreeView existing out of User objects. The TreeView represents the hierarchy of the Users:

- Master1

  - Super1
  - Super2

    - User1
    - User2
  - Super3

    - User3
  - Super4
- Master2
- ...

Every TreeItem is Collapsed when the TreeView is initialized. However, it can be that when the FXML is loaded, a TreeItem object is passed through from another FXML file. Eg: User3 has been passed through:

```
selectedUserTreeItem = (TreeItem<User>) currentNavigation.getPassthroughObject(); //this is the User3 TreeItem
```

I try to use a recursive function to expand all the parent nodes from the `selecterUserTreeItem`

```
if (selectedUserTreeItem != null) {
    expandTreeView(selectedUserTreeItem);
}

tvUsers.setRoot(rootItem);
```

This is what I have so far:

```
private void expandTreeView(TreeItem<User> selectedItem) {        
    if (selectedItem != null) {
        System.out.println(selectedItem);
        if (selectedItem.isLeaf() == false) {
            selectedItem.setExpanded(true);
        }
        TreeItem<User> parent = selectedItem.getParent();
        expandTreeView(parent);
    } else {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
}
```

I think it has to do something with the fact that the function is a void function and it should be returning a TreeItem object I suppose but for some reason I don't succeed in doing it.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I notice that in your expandTreeView() method you expand the node and then you recurse to the previous node to expand that. In my own code I expanded from the root to the leaf, so lets try that:

```
private static <T> void expandTreeView(TreeItem<T> selectedItem) {
    if (selectedItem != null) {
        expandTreeView(selectedItem.getParent());
        if (!selectedItem.isLeaf()) {
            selectedItem.setExpanded(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jurgen, it was the same result but I found the solution in combination with the above! The `selectedItem` is not a TreeItem from the newly initiated TreeView as it is passed through from another FXML file. I have to loop through the initiated TreeView to link the TreeItem from to loop to the selectedItem. Once that is done, the method works as a charm. Thanks a lot for your time and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think its because your method is returning void.
Try setting your TreeView root first before expanding:

```
>>> tvUsers.setRoot(rootItem);

if (selectedUserTreeItem != null) {
    expandTreeView(selectedUserTreeItem);
}
```

If that doesn't work then try wrapping your initial expandTreeView() to run later:

```
Platform.runlater( new Runnable()
{
    public void run() { expandTreeView( selectedUserTreeItem ); }
};
```

Comment: Hi Jurgen, thanks for your response. I've tried it out but it seems to have the same result. It seems to cycle correct through the nodes eg: `User1 - Super2 (expanding) - Master1 (expanding)`. I just don't get it :)

Comment: Ok, hoped the above would work in your case. See next suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the same problem and found that I had to delay the expansion a bit like this:

```
    Platform.runlater( new Task<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception
        {
            Thread.sleep( 250 );
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded()
        {
            expandTreeView( selectedUserTreeItem );
        }

    } );
```

You may have to try and vary the delay to get it to work in your case.

Comment: Hey Jurgen, thanks again! I've tried your suggestion above bit it seems to have the same result. The TreeItems are not expanding for some reason... Even tried it with 2500ms

Comment: Did you move tvUsers.setRoot(rootItem) to before the expandTreeView() method call ?

Comment: Hi Jurgen, yes I did. Seems to have no effect.